# while getting text from Edit-text how to change variable and then show into another Edit-text

Tags: android

```
ed2.setText(String.valueOf(day_x + "/" + month_x + "/" + year_x));
String value = ed2.getText().toString();
ed4.setText(value);
```

after getting the value from ed2 i want to change the year_x while showing in new edittext i.e ed4.

Comment: What is your current issue with your code?

Comment: just use your year_x variable again, change it and concatenate them to a new string.

Comment: Thanks Jonas Köritz,you understand my question. Can you plz write the code.?i tried it my self but it doesnot work.

Comment: @JonasKöritz plz write code for me to solve this ...?

Comment: Try it yourself and we will find your errors. I will not work for you for free.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead=

```
ed2.setText(day_x+"/"+month_x+"/"+year_x);
String value = ed2.getText().toString();
ed4.setText(value);
```

Comment: It doesnot work.i successfully get the value in ed4 after getting values from ed2, but the problem is that i want to edit "year_x" value and then show it to ed4.?

Comment: @mohsinkhan You want to edit year_x value. Can you explain what you actually want to edit from "year_x" or want you want from the code??

Comment: i want to add year_x by 10 and then show it into new edittext i.e ed4. the other two parameters i.e day_x and month_x will remain same when showing to ed4.plz solve my problem...?